# Testing object equality, i.e. the same physical address?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am checking if an object I am getting back from the NSURLConnectionDataDelegate is the same object that I originally created. What I have been doing is:

```
// TESTING TO SEE IF THE RETURNED OBJECT IS THE SAME ONE I CREATED
if(connection == [self connectionPartial]) {
```

But was just curious is this is the same as doing:

```
if([connection isEqual:[self connectionPartial]]) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's **not** the same.

```
if(connection == [self connectionPartial]) {
```

This compares the **address** of the objects, eg. if the pointers point to the same instance.

```
if([connection isEqual:[self connectionPartial]]) {
```

This compares the **contents** of the objects. For instance for two separate `NSString` instances, this will return `YES` as long as the string content is the same:

```
NSString *s1 = @"Something";
NSString *s2 = @"Something";
BOOL sameInstances = (s1 == s2);    // will be false, since they are separate objects.
BOOL sameContent = [s1 isEqual:s2]; // will be true, because they both are "Something"
```

Comment: Much appreciated, as I said I had done the == (and checked in the debugger that the addresses matched) but I noticed isEqual: and even after looking at the docs was not exactly sure what it did.

Answer (score 1):

The first snippet compares the values of the pointers themselves, just as if they were any primitive type like an `int`. If the addresses are the same, the expression will evaluate true.

The second sends the message `isEqual:` to one of the connection instances. Any class can override `isEqual:` to define "equality" with another instance. It's entirely possible for a class's implementation of `isEqual:` to be:

```
- (BOOL)isEqual: (id)obj
{
    return arc4random_uniform(2) ? YES: NO;
}
```

So, no, for almost all classes they are not equivalent. (`NSObject`, which has the "default" implementation of `isEqual:`, uses the objects' `hash`es, which, again by default, are their addresses.)

It sounds like using the equality operator, `==`, is correct in your case.

Comment: Note that you should also override `hash` if you override `isEqual:` and return the same value for objects that are equal.